# Is it possible for `sudo` to fail temporarily with the correct password? Hacking suspected

Tags: linux, security, ssh, root, sudo

TL;DR: `sudo` with the correct password failed repeatedly in my home server but it suddenly started to success after a few minutes. Can this behavior be explained without assuming the existence of an attacker who has the root privilege?

---

This morning, I read [*The xz package has been backdoored - Arch Linux News*](https://archlinux.org/news/the-xz-package-has-been-backdoored/), which strongly advises the users who use `xz 5.6.0-1` or `xz 5.6.1-1` to upgrade their systems.

After that,

1. I opened my laptop to connect to my Arch Linux server in my home, which is also publicly accessible via a private key, via SSH and executed `sudo pacman -Sy` to prepare for upgrading my system.
2. I was prompted the user's password so I typed the correct one. However, all of the three attempts failed:

   ```bash
   $ sudo pacman -Sy
   [sudo] password for user:
   Sorry, try again.
   [sudo] password for user:
   Sorry, try again.
   [sudo] password for user:
   sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
   ```
3. Then, just in case, I configured my router to disable port forwaring, making my server inaccessible outside LAN. (Only I can connect to the server now.)
4. After that, I repeatedly tried `sudo` many times while confirming I didn't enable CAPS_LOCK etc. I also tried to connect to the server from iPhone and execute `sudo`. All of the attempts failed. This was EXTREMELY strange as I connect to the server everyday; the possibility where I typed incorrect passwords for every attempt is very low.
5. A few minutes later, `sudo` suddenly started to success (with the same password).

Can this behavior be explained without assuming the existence of an attacker who has the root privilege?

Comment: *This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers.* OK. `sudo` is not a tool primarily used by programmers though Stack Overflow has `#sudo` tag. I don't agree.